# Can't get the value of a multiselect in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
        if ($request->input('workerRGroup.sAgent')) {
            $worker->isAgent = 1;
        }

        if ($request->input('workerRGroup.supervisor')) {
            $worker->isSupervisor = 1;
        }

        if ($request->input('workerRGroup.human')) {
            $worker->isHuman = 1;
        }

        if ($request->input('workerRGroup.tech')) {
            $worker->isTechnical = 1;
        }
```

That's what I've tried, laravel docs said something with dots, so I used `workerRGroup` which is the name of the select and the value of the select options.

This is my html

```
<label><b>Rank Group</b>
        <select multiple name="workerRGroup[]">
          <option value="sAgent">Security Agent</option>
          <option value="supervisor">Supervisor</option>
          <option value="human">Human Resources</option>
          <option value="tech">Technical</option>
        </select>
      </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `workerRGroup` has as array like `['sAgent', 'supervisor']` so issue is that `workerRGroup` is a key and it has value like `['sAgent', 'supervisor']` so if we talk about `supervisor` is not a key it a value and it's key is `1`

so you can access it like `$request->workerRGroup[1]` // supervisor

if you have to check it so you can do like this

```
if (in_array('sAgent', $request->workerRGroup)) {
    $worker->isAgent = 1;
}

    ....
```